# Posting to Facebook as Links instead of Posting as Facebook Objects using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, object, hyperlink

I am trying to use the Graph API to post on the wall of the authenticated user.

The issue which I am facing is when I try to share a post e.g.

http://www.facebook.com/surendrakumar.in/posts/486644641373819

using Graph API to the users feed

```
$story_url = "http://www.facebook.com/surendrakumar.in/posts/486644641373819"
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
array(
 'access_token' => $fb_access_token,
 'link' => $story_url,
 'message' => ($msg != "" ? $msg : "")
));
```

Then the post which is getting shared in the Facebook is only a link, which is not expected.

Expected :

Post on the wall with http://www.facebook.com/surendrakumar.in/posts/486644641373819 link and details of the post, preview etc.

Actual:

Only a link is posted. no preview, and any other information.

Answer (score 0):

Put the link within the message text.

I.E.:

```
$story_url = "http://www.facebook.com/surendrakumar.in/posts/486644641373819"
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
array(
 'access_token' => $fb_access_token,
 'message' => ($msg != "" ? $msg."\n".$story_url : "".$story_url)
));
```

Comment: Sorry @Tommy but its again not working as expected:

Only the Link :

http://www.facebook.com/surendrakumar.in/posts/486644641373819

is getting posted with message if any.

Thanks for helping. But need more help.